# python asyncio - ConnectionResetError on one async server closes also second server

Tags: python-asyncio, python-sockets, pytest-aiohttp

I have a question regarding two async servers that run on the same event loop. when I close one connection from client side, I see that the second server stops as well.

Here is my code:

```
async def http_server(addr: str, port: int, verbose: int):
     runner = aiohttp.AppRunner(await init_app())
     await runner.setup()
     site = web.TCPSite(runner, str(addr), port)
     await site.start()

async def main(port: int, addr: str, verbose: int, restapiport: int):
    
    # HTTP server
    await http_server(str(addr), restapiport, verbose)
    print(f'Serving RPC on {addr}:{restapiport} ...')
    
    # TCP server for messaging
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, str(addr), port)
    addr = server.sockets[0].getsockname()
    print(f'Serving MBE on {addr} CSID={os.environ["CSID"]}')
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()
```

When I close one connection from client side I get the following Exception (which is ok):

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<handle_client() done, defined at /opt/xenv.py:19> 
exception=ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/xenv.py", line 41, in handle_client
data = await reader.readexactly(msg_headers.X_MSG_TCP_DATA_BUF_SIZE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py", line 679, in readexactly
await self._wait_for_data('readexactly')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py", line 473, in _wait_for_data
await self._waiter
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 814, in _ 
_read_ready__data_received
data = self._sock.recv(self.max_size)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

it seems that ConnectionResetError exception somehow impacts the other asynchronous tasks. How can I handle this exception without having an impact on the other async task?

here is netstat before the exception:

```
root@5901ff922714:/opt# netstat 
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 5901ff922714:34833      symulator_pm-b_1.:33330 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 5901ff922714:34271      5901ff922714:25010      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 5901ff922714:36695      5901ff922714:33330      ESTABLISHED
tcp     8192      0 5901ff922714:25010      5901ff922714:34271      ESTABLISHED
tcp    49152      0 5901ff922714:33330      5901ff922714:36695      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 5901ff922714:40831      symulator_pm-b_1.:25011 ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830805 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830724 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830804 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830725 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    396819365
```

here is netstat after the exception:

```
root@5901ff922714:/opt# netstat 
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830805 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830724 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830804 
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     396830725
```

any help would be much appreciated